# C++ Missing Windows API Headers

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, header-files

I'm trying to create a C++ Project in Visual Studio 2022, but the only problem is that I'm missing all of the Windows API headers (Windows.h, Toolhelp32, PSApi, all that good stuff), however, I do have the standard stuff, like `<iostream>`.

Because I do not have the Windows API headers, this means that I can not compile DLL projects.

[image]

I have tried 'Retarget solution' but it solves nothing.

Prior to all of this, I did reinstall VS entirely.

I do have the C++ and .NET workloads/packages installed with EVERY optional download for C++.

I have also tried going into the project properties and changing SDK version.

**Edit:**
So, adding these include directories manually seemed to fix the include errors, however, I now get an error about the version of Windows SDK.

[image]

Comment: Run the VS installer and check the box for "Windows SDK version (something)" and then go back to your project and target that version.

Comment: Those? https://imgur.com/wEb1kLQ

Comment: Then it seems that Visual Studio can't find where they got installed. Look in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots` at the `KitsRoot` and confirm that you have an `Include' subdirectory with header files inside it.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you meant.
But I had included these.
https://imgur.com/J7Qfjs4


The top one for what I thought you meant, and the two below the top one for the Windows.h file.

Comment: It looks like you reconfigured the project from 20348 to 18362 to 22000. Whichever version you picked (say, 22000), check if the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0` exists. If not, pick one that exists.

Comment: All of the directories exist.
https://imgur.com/gKhpCBT

I've directed all of my include directories towards 10.0.20348.0
https://imgur.com/D8DjTD7

Comment: Then I can't explain.

Comment: Have you tried to recreate a dll project or repair Visual Studio? Does this problem occur in other projects?

Comment: I have tried to recreate a dll project.
I have tried repairing Visual Studio.
I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio.
And this problem occurs in every project.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, I doubt it, but I am currently on Windows 11.

I had tried uninstalling everything that I could find related to Visual Studio to hope for a real 'fresh reset', but it didn't seem to fix anything.

The issue started after installing the Windows Kernel Driver SDK for windows.

Comment: I've recently tried deleting every registry that contained 'Visual Studio'/'VisualStudio' and 'Windows Kits', deleting every folder that had 'VisualStudio'/'Visual Studio' in it's name and it has solved literally nothing, still stuck where I started.

Comment: Created an empty project with only `main` defined but it seems to not like that too.
https://imgur.com/ySgb42a